# ¿Por qué obtengo este error con la foto mouse.png en Python? Librería tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Muy buenas, estoy creadno una interfaz gráfica muy simple y quiero añadir una imagen en png, pero obtengo el siguiente error:

_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "mouse.png": no such file or directory

La imagen la tengo en la misma carpeta donde tengo el archivo que estoy ejecutando. Este es el código:

```
from tkinter import *

from numpy import imag

root = Tk()
# Frame 
miFrame = Frame(root, width=500,height=400)
miFrame.pack()

# Root
root.title('Práctica Label')

# Imagen
miImagen = PhotoImage(file="mouse.png")

# Label
Label(miFrame, image=miImagen).place(x=100,y=200)

# miLabel.pack() # Cuando utilizamos el pack con el label adapta el contenedor
# Main Loop
root.mainloop()
```

¿Alguien sabe cuál puede ser el problema? Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Estás ejecutando el script desde su misma ruta? Estás seguro de que el archivo se llama así? Ten en cuenta que es case sensitive

Comment: Totalmente, el archivo se llama mouse.png y lo tengo en la misma carpeta que el script. No se si será problema de que no acepta png la librería, pero lo dudo.

Comment: qué te devuelve `os.getcwd()`? la misma ruta en donde están tanto el script como el png?

Comment: Pero dónde ingreso esa linea, en el código o en la terminal. Y si es en el código,¿la imprimo por pantalla con print?

Comment: Ese comando te devuelve el path de el directorio de trabajo. Debes ver qué te devuelve (con un print por ejemplo, sí) en la ejecución del propio script.

Comment: El os no me lo reconoce en el código

Comment: obviamente tienes que importarlo antes de usarlo, se me olvidó especificarlo: `import os` y listo

Comment: Es curioso porque me sigue dando error: No module named '_tkinter'. De todas maneras en Visual Studio Code no me está dando ningún problema a la hora del case sensitive y no me devuelve ningún tipo de error

Comment: Ese error se debe a que tu instalación de python no tiene tkinter. Si antes no te pasaba y ahora sí es debido a que antes estabas utilizando un intérprete diferente. De cualquier manera, es un problema diferente al de la pregunta. Pudiste comprobar si la ruta de `os.getcwd()` es en la que está el png?

Comment: Pues no he podido hacerlo ya que me ha aparecido este nuevo error: No module named '_tkinter'. He vuelto a instalarlo con pip3 install tk pero no funciona. No se me ocurre otra idea.